# Create App installer for windows - Electron (electron-packager, electron-builder)

Tags: windows-installer, installation, desktop-application, electron, electron-builder

Can someone help me with the following queries.

**Whats the difference between the two?** `electron-packager` and `electron-builder`.

I have used both. And both of them creates a .exe file.

But the one created with builder can be used independently(requires no other files)

The problem with the app(created from electron-builder) is that, everytime I run the app(MyApp) on Windows OS, there's something else(interface) that loads up, and then it takes a while for the app to start(maybe around 7-8 secs).

Have attached an image:
[image]

Why can't I create an installer like other windows application. Where I install it once, and then run it from `Programs -> MyApp`

Please help/guide

Thank you !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Whats the difference between the two? electron-packager and electron-builder.

electron-builder includes electron-packager. electron-packager only pack your app, but electron-builder pack, build in distributable format (e.g. dmg, setup exe, AppImage) and publish to GitHub Releases or Bintray.

> The problem with the app(created from electron-builder) is that, everytime I run the app(MyApp) on

You should handle Squirrel.Windows events, please see https://github.com/electron/windows-installer#handling-squirrel-events

> Why can't I create an installer like other windows application.

Using electron-builder, you can — just set `build.win.target` to `nsis` and `build.nsis.perMachine` to `true`. Please see all available options — https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Options#NsisOptions

Comment: Any idea, about how do you I update the desktop app?? Via Squirrel right? Can you guide me through the same?? Please help !!

Comment: If you use Squirrel.Windows target (default) — yes, using Squirrel.Windows. If you use NSIS — auto-update is not yet ready to use.

Comment: Any links you can point me to?? Also to use the auto-update, I would have to then set the `build.win.target` to `squirrel`. But then will it work like an installer(like nsis)?

Comment: To integrate the auto-update feature into the windows app, one has to build it using Squirrel.Windows. But the problem is when I build it using squirrel, I cant install the app(like the way the NSIS works)

Comment: can you answer the above comments?